# How to deactivate the "Inspection 'Annotator' Options" from context actions in IntelliJ

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, annotations, inspection

Whenever I want to use context actions (⌥↩) to, for example, add a missing import, I have the following option appear first, and I have to select it twice for my import proposal options to appear.

[image: context action that appears when using the shortcut ⌥↩]

How can I deactivate this and get the right context actions the first time?

[image: correct context action after the first one has been selected twice]

Please note this happens on a Flutter/Dart project, and I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) [Build #IU-213.7172.25, built on March 16, 2022] on macOS Monterey v12.2.1

Comment: - how the library (the one suggested for import) is added/related to the project?
- does it happen with any other imports (e.g. when library is already imported and you need a static method import)?

also worth trying on the latest 2022.2 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion

Comment: @quickfix it's not an external library, it's a dart file within my project. It does happen with any imports. I just upgraded to the recommended 2022.1.3 (Build #IU-221.5921.22, built on June 21, 2022) but the same thing happens.

Comment: please file a request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with logs and a sample project to reproduce the issue

Comment: @quickfix I've created the issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/48407 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55217